# Programmatically Edit Excel Drop-Down Items

Tags: c#, excel, vba, automation

I have thousands upon thousands of Excel files, all made from the same template.  Each has columns for parameters like date, part number, and engineer.  The engineer cells are set to drop-down lists so the user can only enter the names of certain engineers.  When we want to add new engineers or get rid of ones who have left, we currently change the list of names in Microsoft Script Editor as needed:

```
<x:DataValidation>
     <x:Range>$D$19:$D$37</x:Range>
     <x:Type>List</x:Type>
     <x:CellRangeList/>
     **<x:Value>&quot;Peter, Paul, Mary&quot;</x:Value>**
</x:DataValidation>
```

Every time we come across an Excel file we haven't updated in a while, we have to press ctrl+F11, find the line with "Peter, Paul, Mary" and manually change it to "Peter, John, Susan".  This gets very annoying and I'd like to edit the above data and replace "Peter, Paul, Mary" with "Peter, John, Susan".  I'd like to do this for every Excel file whose filename ends with "ABC".  Is there a code solution for this rather than hunting down every file and manually changing it?  I prefer C++/C# but can manage with Visual Basic if I need to or if it would be easier.

Comment: If you know which cells have data validation applied then you could quite easily create a VBA macro to do the updates: try recording a macro while setting the list, and modift that. What about files which were created when "past" engineers were still present? Doesn't that data still require access to the "old" list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all of this with COM interop.  Make sure your project has Excel interop referenced. (you need excel installed on your machine i believe)

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then the app

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mypath = @"c:\my\search\directory";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mypath, "*abc.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Find(Path.Combine(mypath,file));
        }
    }

    private static void Find(string path)
    {
        object missing = null;
        Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Excel.Range firstFind = null;
        var app = new Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];


        Excel.Range foundNames = worksheet.Range["A1", "B3"];
        // You should specify all these parameters every time you call this method, 
        // since they can be overridden in the user interface. 
        currentFind = foundNames.Find("Peter, Paul, Mary", LookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart);

        currentFind.Replace(What:"Peter, Paul, Mary", Replacement:"Peter, John, Susan");

        workbook.Save();
    }
}
```

This example assumes that everything is on the first worksheet within A1 and B3.  Obviously, your worksheets will be different so these values will need to be changed to reflect that.
Also, you could remove the "visible=true", might speed things up.  I only did that so that I could see what my app was doing.

Comment: Thank you! This works for the most part.  I had to make a few small fixes to the Find method.  I used the Validation interface instead of the Find/Replace, which I couldn't get to work properly.  I also made the method close the workbook after saving it using `workbook.Close()`.  This is important so Excel isn't left running in the background.